# DrawingArea inside scrolledwindow fails to draw

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am trying to make an image viewer in PyGTK by drawing an opened image on a drawing area within a scrolled window. For some reason, the image is not drawing. Here's the code for the viewer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk
import math
import time

class ImageViewerGTK:
    def __init__(self):

        self.filename = ""

        #Set the Glade file
        self.gladefile = "issue.glade"  
        self.builder = gtk.Builder();
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("window")
        self.image = self.builder.get_object("image")
        self.image.set_events(gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.builder.get_object("window").show_all()

        self.zoom_slider = self.builder.get_object("zoomlevel")
        self.constrast_slider = self.builder.get_object("contrastlevel")

        self.style = self.image.get_style()
        self.gc = self.style.fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
        self.thumnail_pixmap = gtk.gdk.Pixmap(self.window.get_window(), 25, 25)
        self.mouse_pressed = False

        self.scroll_window = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow1")
        self.scroll_vertical = self.scroll_window.get_vadjustment()
        self.scroll_horizontal = self.scroll_window.get_hadjustment()

        self.statusbar = self.builder.get_object("statusbar")

        self.clickX = 0
        self.clickY = 0

    def on_window_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit();

    def on_open_image_activate(self, menuItem, data=None):
        filename = self.get_open_filename()
        if filename: self.load_file(filename)

    def get_open_filename(self):

        filename = None
        chooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open File...", self.window,
                gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, 
                    gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

        response = chooser.run()
        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK: filename = chooser.get_filename()
        chooser.destroy()

        return filename 

    def load_file(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.clickX = 0
        self.clickY = 0
        self.pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(self.filename)
        pixmap, mask = self.pixbuf.render_pixmap_and_mask()
        self.image.set_size_request(self.pixbuf.get_width(), self.pixbuf.get_height())
        self.image.window.draw_drawable(self.gc, pixmap, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1)

    def image_motion_notify_event_cb(self, widget, event):
       if self.filename != "":
           pixel = self.pixbuf.get_pixels_array()[event.y][event.x]
           self.statusbar.pop(3)
           message = "Gray level: " + str(self.gray_level(pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2])) + " @ " + str(event.x) + ", " + str(event.y)
           self.statusbar.push(3, message)

    def gray_level(self, r, g, b):
        return int(0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   try:
       hwg= ImageViewerGTK()
       gtk.main()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       pass
```

and the gladefile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkAccelGroup" id="accelgroup1"/>
  <object class="GtkAction" id="action1"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Image Viewer</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_File</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="open_image">
                        <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Open a new image.</property>
                        <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                        <signal name="activate" handler="on_open_image_activate" swapped="no"/>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Edit</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu2">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem9">
                        <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem3">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_View</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem4">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Help</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu3">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem10">
                        <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
            <property name="width_request">512</property>
            <property name="height_request">512</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="hscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
            <property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkViewport" id="viewport1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkDrawingArea" id="image">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkStatusbar" id="statusbar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="spacing">2</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

The image draws properly if the set_size_request line is removed, so the act of changing the drawing area size renders it unable to draw anything. Why is this?

Comment: particular reason you are not using the gio.introspection with python3?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and Pygtk 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `GtkDrawingArea` incorrectly. A drawing area is not a canvas on which you can draw only once and expect the system to refresh the drawing; it is a widget that allows (and requires) you to draw on it during the `expose` event. This is useful when you need to process the image, e.g. by scaling it to the area. If all you just need is a widget to show an existing image, use `gtk.Image` instead.

To use a `DrawingArea` correctly, you must subclass from it and handle the expose event. For example:

```
import gtk, gobject

class ImageArea(gtk.DrawingArea):
    __gsignals__ = {'expose-event': 'override'}

    def __init__(self, pixbuf):
        super(ImageArea, self).__init__()
        self._pixbuf = pixbuf

    def do_expose_event(self, event):
        # clip to exposed area
        cr = self.window.cairo_create()
        cr.rectangle(tuple(event.area))
        cr.clip()
        _, _, w, h = tuple(self.allocation)

        # paint over the drawing context:
        pb = self._pixbuf
        cr.set_source_pixbuf(pb, (w - pb.get_width()) / 2, (h - pb.get_height()) / 2)
        cr.paint()

gobject.type_register(ImageArea)
```

Comment: Would this be different from setting an expose event handler on the drawing area?

Comment: @aftrumpet In theory it wouldn't be different, but I haven't tried it. Using `do_expose_event` is usually a better idea because it doesn't rely on signal dispatch and leaves it to the widget to handle its own refreshes.

Comment: So I tried using the expose event and this works, however now the image redraws itself every time the scrollbars are adjusted, which makes for a really slow scrolling experience. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @aftrumpet Did you use the `do_expose_event` approach, or the expose signal approach? We use this kind of code in production, and even scale the pixmap on the fly, and it works remarkably snappy.

Comment: The expose signal. The problem is that the image shouldn't need to be redrawn every time a scrollbar is moved, but that is what is currently happening.

Comment: @aftrumpet Actually, the image does need be redrawn every time the scrollbar is moved, otherwise moving the scrollbar would have no effect. On my (quite old) computer, handling the expose event as shown above takes 2ms for a 600x1030 sample image. Larger images will take more time, so if you are dealing with very large images, you will need to be more efficient and replace the clipping with an operation that only copies the visible part of the image. Implementing this optimization is IMO beyond the scope of this question.